# strrev not working when comparing in an if statement

Tags: c++, c-strings

PD: I am forced to learn "strrev()" as this is part of my bachelors degree, please do not consider recommending me "reverse()".

---

```
int n = 0, str, revc=0;

char a[256], v[101][21], *p, sep[]=" :;.,", rev[256];

cin.get(a, 256);

p = strtok(a, sep);

while(p){
    
    strcpy(v[n++], p);

    p = strtok(NULL, sep);

}

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

    str = strlen(v[i]);

    if(stricmp(strrev(v[i]), v[i]) == 0 && str > revc){

        strcpy(rev, v[i]);

        revc = str;
    }

}

cout << rev;
```

### Code explanation & Problem encountered

#### **The purpose of this code is to find the longest palindromic word in array (a)

---

The first part of the code tokenizes the whole "a" array, separators being "sep".
The second part of the code searches in v if it has any palindromic words; For instance if a is:

> 121 hellO WorlD;  this Isi  An eXample

it **should** realise that no matter the capitalization of the the only palindromic word in a ("***Isi***") is also greater than revc (0 at this time), so "***Isi***" should copy into rev.

However it finds "***eXample***" as being a palindromic word. Also, it copies the reverse form of "***eXample***" into rev for some reason. Why is this?

Comment: `strrev()` doesn't exist in the C++ Standard Library? I see the `cout`, but this is *barely* a C++ question, and is more of a C question. I'm apparently bad at this, I can't find a page for `strrev()` at all outside of a geeksforgeeks page. Same with `stricmp()`.

Comment: I understand @RemyLebeau. Out of curiosity though, if I ever got to use reverse instead of strrev there, would it pass it to stricmp() right away or does it have the same behaviour as strrev()?

Comment: @JustDragos Using `std::reverse()` would exhibit the same problem, as it is also an in-place modifier. You would still need to make a copy of the content of `v[i]`, but you could use `std::reverse_copy()` to reverse the content of `v[i]` and assign the output to that copy rather than back into `v[i]`.

Comment: @sweenish strrev() is found in the cstring library

Comment: @anastaciu the `-1` is wrong, the 2nd parameter needs to be 1-past-the-last, which is `end()` by itself

Comment: @JustDragos It's not part of the standard. If it's in `cstring` (like it is in MSVC), it's an extension.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is it? I remeber using it like that, let me check

Comment: @JustDragos While I won't doubt it, it's not documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring), which I consider to be a fairly definitive resource.

Comment: @RemyLebeau anyway it seems the OP doesn't want it, just saw it.

Comment: @JustDragos There are easier ways to check if a word is a palindrome that to reverse the string. Read the string from both ends until you meet in the middle. If all characters on the way are equal, you have a palindrome. See the example at the bottom of [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)

Comment: @RemyLebeau if you do not use -1 the null terminator will also be reversed and the string is effectively empty.

Comment: Fair enough @TedLyngmo, I'll give it a try. Also, thanks all for the answers.

Comment: @anastaciu you are still wrong, the `end()` iterator will point at the null terminator, but it will not include the null terminator in `std::reverse()` (or any other algorithm). [demo](https://ideone.com/fVskJM). The null terminator exists in memory, but it is not counted in the string's `size()`, or included in iterator ranges over the string's content

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you are thinking of `std::string`, but with a C style array, it's not the case https://godbolt.org/z/hvhEqW

Comment: @anastaciu With a C style `char[]` string, `std::end()` is wrong to use, since it will ignore the null terminator altogether and use the full array size instead. So you would actually need `std::reverse(std::begin(str), std::begin(str) + strlen(str));` or simply `std::reverse(str, str + strlen(str));` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strrev()` alters the content of the passed `char[]` in-place, and then returns a pointer to that same `char[]`.  It DOES NOT allocate a new string, like your code is assuming.  Thus, the statement:

```cpp
stricmp(strrev(v[i]), v[i])
```

Will *always* return 0, since you are comparing the content of `v[i]` to itself.

To do what you are attempting, you need to first make a separate copy of the content of `v[i]` to another `char[]`, then you can reverse the copy and compare it to the content of the original `v[i]`, eg:

```cpp
bool is_palindrome(const char* s)
{
    char rev[256];
    strcpy(rev, s);
    return stricmp(strrev(rev), s) == 0;
}

char a[256], longest[256], v[101][256], sep[]=" :;.,";
int n = 0, longestc = 0;

cin.get(a, 256);

char *p = strtok(a, sep);
while (p && n < 101) {
    strcpy(v[n++], p);
    p = strtok(NULL, sep);
}

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int len = strlen(v[i]);
    if (len > longestc && is_palindrome(v[i])) {
        strcpy(longest, v[i]);
        longestc = len;
    }
}

cout << longest;
```

Which can be simplified further if you get rid of the `v[]` array and the 2nd loop completely, as they are redundant:

```cpp
bool is_palindrome(const char* s)
{
    char rev[256];
    strcpy(rev, s);
    return stricmp(strrev(rev), s) == 0;
}

char a[256], longest[256], sep[]=" :;.,";
int longestc = 0;

cin.get(a, 256);

char *p = strtok(a, sep);
while (p) {
    int len = strlen(p);
    if (len > longestc && is_palindrome(p)) {
        strcpy(longest, p);
        longestc = len;
    }
    p = strtok(NULL, sep);
}

cout << rev;
```

---

However, I do not recommend this style of C coding in C++, you really should be using C++ features instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctype>

bool is_palindrome(const std::string_view& s)
{
    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin(),
        [](char a, char b) { return tolower(a) == tolower(b); }
    );
}
 
std::string a;
std::getline(cin, a);

std::string_view v = a, word, longest;

std::string_view::size_type start = 0, end;
do {
    end = vec.find_first_of(" :;.,", start);
    if (end == std::string_view::npos) {
        word = v.substr(start);
        start = end;
    } else {
        word = v.substr(start, end-start);
        start = end + 1;
    }
    if (word.size() > longest.size() && is_palindrome(word)) {
        longest = word;
    }
}
while (start != std::string_view::npos);

cout << longest;
```